# bash variable expansion as parameter

Tags: bash, variable

I have a command (zip, but nevermind) in which I have a parameter like

```
cmd /foo/bar/{*.php,*.css,images/}
```

I would like to put it in a variable to pass it to the command as :

```
VAR=/foo/bar/{*.php,*.css,images/}
cmd ${VAR}
```

But, whatever I try, it never expand as I want. I tried with or without quotes, but not better.

**EDIT:**

(No answer possible because closed)
I hadn't been able to find it, but the solution did exist:

```
VAR=(/foo/bar/{*.php,*.css,images/})
cmd ${VAR[@]}
```

Comment: Please be specific.  Don't say "it does not do what I want."  Specify what you _do_ want, and show what your attempt _does_ (and indeed what you attempted), so that the contrast between what was desired and what is created is explicit.

Comment: All is indicated in the question. I want : cmd /foo/bar/{*.php,*.css,images/}